# PHP array sort keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've a simple multi array as described below that I need to order by its key label (not by key value).

```
array(
    1 => array(
        2 => array();
        11 => array();
        20 => array();
        31 => array();
        4 => array();
        43 => array();
        12 => array();
        3 => array();
    );
    2 => array();
    11 => array();
    20 => array();
    31 => array();
    4 => array();
    43 => array();
    12 => array();
    3 => array(); );
```

The problem is that my ordering is returning my arrays ordered like:

`1, 11, 12, 2, 20, 3, 31,` etc...
And not `1,2,3,4,11,12,` etc..

This is my ordering function:

```
private function orderByKey(&$array) {
        ksort($array);
        foreach($array as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->orderByKey($value);
            }
        }
    }
```

What might be wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access $value as a reference to the entry in $array

```
private function orderByKey(&$array) {
        ksort($array);
        foreach($array as &$value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->orderByKey($value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was in fact the problem, not referencing my $value.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for i.e. sort() and ksort() is the sort_flags. When you want it to be sorted by number, and not on string value (as it currently looks like) you have to set that parameter:

```
ksort($my_array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Check out the page for sort() where the different sort flags are explained: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: That's not the issue, here. It's a reference/value problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`natksort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php#49150) function.

Answer (score 1):

Next to not sorting the sub-arrays I also read your question that you've got a problem to sort the keys in the order you outline in your question (`1, 11, 12, 2, 20, 3, 31, ...`):

```
uksort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp("$a ", "$b ");
});
```

This sort does pad each key with spaces so that 3 is larger than 20 but smaller than 30.

The full code:

```
private function orderByKey(&$array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) return;
    uksort($array, function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp("$a ", "$b ");
    });
    array_walk($array, [$this, 'orderByKey']);
}
```

Or if `ksort()` works for you:

```
private function orderByKey(&$array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) return;
    ksort($array);        
    array_walk($array, [$this, 'orderByKey']);
}
```

Comment: There's no problem with spaces, my text was edited by someone for better readability, I guess. Ãnyways, thanks for the cleanup of "orderByKey" function :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Is what you search; instead of ksort:

```
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $a - $b; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ksort($myarray);
 foreach ($myarray as $key => $val) {
     echo "$key = $val\n";
 }
```